PostgreSQL Query, Trying to Get 4 Possible Outcomes With Parameters and NULL Value Complications
I am trying to make a PostgreSQL code where I am able to display four different possible outcomes using parameters. I have COALESCE(a.id, b.id), which gives the location of an item, however when I was using only one parameter, I couldn't ever see NULL values which are still important to me. I want to write a query that allows for 4 different results possibilities:

No values (No location or NULL values showing)
Only NULL Values (No locations only items where the location is NULL)
Only Location Values (No NULL values, only where the items have an associated location)
All results (All locations and NULL values for all the items included in a single results table)

In my code, the SQL parameters are formatted like:
WHERE 
  COALESCE(a.id, b.id) SIMILAR TO {{ParameterName}}

When you leave the parameter empty the query is executed like the parameter was a NULL value. I tried writing it like:
COALESCE(a.id, b.id) SIMILAR TO {{ParameterName1}} OR COALESCE(a.id, b.id) IS {{ParameterName2}}

This would show all of the values when I set ParameterName1 to "%" but when I tried to put "NOT NULL" into ParameterName2 it would stop working as the query would be executed like:
COALESCE(a.id, b.id) SIMILAR TO "%" OR COALESCE(a.id, b.id) IS "NOT NULL"

The NULL values in the table are also not a BOOLEAN so I couldn't use TRUE or FALSE, and as "NOT NULL" isn't a value in the table no results came up.
